# Problems with GNU Arm and Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, arm, stm32, gnu-arm

Last days I've been trying to set up GNU ARM plugin with Eclipse on **Linux**.
The problem is I can't properly compile for my STM32 Discovery F4 board.
There are no problems with compiling normal gcc ARM project, but when it comes to STM32F4xx I am getting these errors:

```
13:26:22 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project F4Test ****
make all 
Building file: ../system/src/newlib/_cxx.cpp
Invoking: Cross ARM C++ Compiler
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -Os -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wextra  -g -DOS_USE_TRACE_ITM -DSTM32F407xx -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DHSE_VALUE=8000000 -I"../include" -I"../system/include" -I"../system/include/cmsis" -I"../system/include/stm32f4-hal" -std=gnu++11 -fabi-version=0 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -MP -MF"system/src/newlib/_cxx.d" -MT"system/src/newlib/_cxx.o" -c -o "system/src/newlib/_cxx.o" "../system/src/newlib/_cxx.cpp"
../system/src/newlib/_cxx.cpp:13:19: fatal error: cstdlib: No such file or directory
 #include <cstdlib>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [system/src/newlib/_cxx.o] Error 1

13:26:22 Build Finished (took 69ms)
```

My code is default led blink one:

```
//
// This file is part of the GNU ARM Eclipse distribution.
// Copyright (c) 2014 Liviu Ionescu.
//

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <stdio.h>


#include "Timer.h"
#include "BlinkLed.h"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// STM32F4 led blink sample (trace via ITM).
//
// In debug configurations, demonstrate how to print a greeting message
// on the trace device. In release configurations the message is
// simply discarded.
//
// To demonstrate POSIX retargetting, reroute the STDOUT and STDERR to the
// trace device and display messages on both of them.
//
// Then demonstrates how to blink a led with 1Hz, using a
// continuous loop and SysTick delays.
//
// On DEBUG, the uptime in seconds is also displayed on the trace device.
//
// Trace support is enabled by adding the TRACE macro definition.
// By default the trace messages are forwarded to the ITM output,
// but can be rerouted to any device or completely suppressed, by
// changing the definitions required in system/src/diag/trace_impl.c
// (currently OS_USE_TRACE_ITM, OS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG/_STDOUT).
//

// ----- Timing definitions -------------------------------------------------

// Keep the LED on for 2/3 of a second.
#define BLINK_ON_TICKS  (TIMER_FREQUENCY_HZ * 2 / 3)
#define BLINK_OFF_TICKS (TIMER_FREQUENCY_HZ - BLINK_ON_TICKS)

// ----- main() ---------------------------------------------------------------

// Sample pragmas to cope with warnings. Please note the related line at
// the end of this function, used to pop the compiler diagnostics status.
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-declarations"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wreturn-type"

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // By customising __initialize_args() it is possible to pass arguments,
  // for example when running tests with semihosting you can pass various
  // options to the test.
  // trace_dump_args(argc, argv);

  // Send a greeting to the trace device (skipped on Release).
  trace_puts("Hello ARM World!");

  // The standard output and the standard error should be forwarded to
  // the trace device. For this to work, a redirection in _write.c is
  // required.
  puts("Standard output message.");
  fprintf(stderr, "Standard error message.\n");

  // At this stage the system clock should have already been configured
  // at high speed.
  trace_printf("System clock: %uHz\n", SystemCoreClock);

  timer_start();

  blink_led_init();

  uint32_t seconds = 0;

  // Infinite loop
  while (1)
    {
      blink_led_on();
      timer_sleep(BLINK_ON_TICKS);

      blink_led_off();
      timer_sleep(BLINK_OFF_TICKS);

      ++seconds;

      // Count seconds on the trace device.
      trace_printf("Second %u\n", seconds);
    }
  // Infinite loop, never return.
}

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried adding cstdlib file to project but then it gets new errors.
Thanks for your help!